# How do I have VS Code only autocomplete names in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

Recently (currently on 1.58.2), it seems like VS Code became far more "helpful" when autocompleting names. Before, I could type

[image: except pydantic.Val]

Then when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> I'd end up with

```
except pydantic.ValidationError
```

but now in cases from built-ins like `int` to third party libraries, VS Code gets *suuuuper* helpful and thinks I want to call it and gives me the signature as a snippet:

[image]

How do I get the "dumber" behavior back? I'm fine for smart, but IMHO I should at least need to signal for it with an open-paren, rather than it vomiting text I need to manually select to remove.

---

My current settings are pretty dull:

```
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
    "gitlens.blame.separateLines": false,
    "gitlens.codeLens.enabled": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--experimental-string-processing"
    ],
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    }
}
```

there's the setting `python.autoComplete.addBrackets` that is currently the default `false`, even if I make it explicit in my settings, or set it `true`, there's no difference as far as I can tell.

Extensions:

```
eamodio.gitlens
EFanZh.graphviz-preview
joaompinto.vscode-graphviz
lextudio.restructuredtext
mechatroner.rainbow-csv
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-python.python
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack
ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings
mscgenjs.vscode-mscgen
rust-lang.rust
samuelcolvin.jinjahtml
sleistner.vscode-fileutils
tamasfe.even-better-toml
tsandall.opa
```

Comment: Do you have Github Copilot? When using Copilot your cursor shouldn't move, and the suggested text should be gray, but could be a possibility...

Comment: Did you maybe install or enable some snippets recently?

Comment: No Copilot, no new extensions. Added the list of extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `JediLSP` Language Server, isn't it?

You can modify the parameter and jump to the next one with `Tab`.

Could you try to switch to `Pylance` Language Server? It is still with the "dumber" behavior. You can set this in the settings.json file:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Comment: That works. Where can I complain about this? I'm not saying the feature is pointless, but fairly frequently one would refer to the literal function, class, type (super annoying for decorators as well)

Comment: @Steven-MSFT It was built-in the Python Extension. So, I think you can submit a feature in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues) and [here](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server/issues)